# Хук на копирование директории (ICopyHook). Изменение атрибута

Tags: delphi, winapi

Вешаю хук на копирование папки. Как в примере от Delphi 7. CopyCallback определяю примерно так:

```
function TCopyHook.CopyCallBack(Wnd: HWND; wFunc, wFlags: UINT; pszSrcFile: LPWSTR;
      dwSrcAttribs: DWORD; pszDestFile: LPWSTR; dwDestAttribs: DWORD): UINT;
// This is the method which is called by the shell for folder operations
const
  ConfirmMessage = 'Are you sure you want to %s ''%s''?';
var
  Operation: string;
  Attr: Cardinal;
begin
 Result := IDYES;

 if wFunc = FO_COPY then
  begin
   Attr:= GetFileAttributes(pszSrcFile);

   dwDestAttribs:=   Attr;

// Лог
CodeSite.Send( 'dwSrcAttribs', dwSrcAttribs );   
CodeSite.Send( ' dwDestAttribs = ' +IntToStr (dwDestAttribs));

   {
   Result := IDNO;
   // Вместо обычного копирования вызываем XCopy
   ShellExecute(0, 'Open', 'xcopy', PWideChar('/I /K '+pszSrcFile+' '+pszDestFile), '', SW_HIDE);
    }
  end;

end;
```

Суть в том, что бы в папке назначения были те же атрибуты, что и в исходной папке.
Компиляю 64 битный проект. Проверяю на Win 10 64.

Метод срабатывает CodeSite показывает правильное значения атрибута. Тем не менее, атрибуты в папке назначения не изменяются, т.е. Attr = 16, вне зависимости от значения атрибутов исходной папки.
Если, допустим, папка Read Only, то CodeSite покажет 17 (что правильно). Но по факту новая папка не будет Read Only и GetFileAttributes для неё вернет 16.

Суть в том, что бы при копировании папки копировались и ее атрибуты. Самое интересное, что в Win 8 и в Win 7 все работает правильно и без хуков. При копировании папки средствами эксплорер копируются и её атрибуты.

Можно, конечно, подменять стандартное копирование вызовом XCopy, но это как-то не спортивно.

Есть ли какой-то способ научить эксплорер копировать атрибуты при копировании папки?

Comment: В win10 копирование атрибутов не работает из-за бага, который уже судя по всему исправлен: [Folder attributes/customization lost on copy or move in Windows 10 1607 (Anniversary Update)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab1a753-9a63-4273-8ba4-0d0748cc9ac0/folder-attributescustomization-lost-on-copy-or-move-in-windows-10-1607-anniversary-update?forum=win10itprogeneral)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам вызывать вручную SetFileAttributes для pszDestFile.

*P.S. Строка `dwDestAttribs := Attr;` не имеет ни малейшего смысла, т.к. `dwDestAttribs` не var-параметр.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

А как это лучше сделать? Ведь на момент вызова CopyCallBack еще не создан. И далеко не факт, что имя папки назначения будет именно pszDestFile. Если папка с таким именем уже существует, то исходная директория будет скопирована в другую папку. Например New Folder(1). Ну, допустим имя папки я определю, но всё же как отловить момент ее создания, что бы установить нужные атрибуты?